# StringBuilder and CharSequence incompatible

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java language and now following the Oracle Java tutorial to gain more insight of this language. When I'm studying the Interface part, I got confused when I tried to do the exercise:

"Write a class that implements the CharSequence interface found in the java.lang package. Your implementation should return the string backwards. Select one of the sentences from this book to use as the data. Write a small main method to test your class; make sure to call all four methods."

When I'm doing this, I found something strange. At first, I download the java.lang.CharSequence interface source code and add it as an interface file in my home directory, and **my implementation of the 'subSequence' complains that the StringBuilder cannot be casted to CharSequence type.**

Here is the code:

```
public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
    if (start < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(start);
    }
    if (end > s.length()) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(end);
    }
    if (start > end) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(start - end);
    }
    StringBuilder sub = 
        new StringBuilder(s.subSequence(fromEnd(end), fromEnd(start)));
    return sub.reverse();
}
```

But when I delete my local file of CharSequence interface, the java compiler finds out that I'm implementing the 'java.lang.CharSequence' interface instead of a local package, **then the compiling error disappears.**

Just curious about this. What's the difference between the local interface file and the library interface file? And what causes the compiling error in the beginning?

Comment: You **don't** download `CharSequence`. It comes with Java.

Comment: If you've downloaded the source file file for Java's own CharSequence interface, I have to wonder if you've changed the full package-specific name of it. Understand that a class's name is more than just it's "name", but it also includes the package names as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a "local interface file".

You made a completely new, unrelated interface that happens to have the same name as an interface in the JRE.

You use types defined in the JRE directly from their packages, without downloading anything.

Comment: So here's my understanding: CharSequence is an interface that defined in the library(JDK), and cannot be re-declared. If I want to define my own interface, the name shall be different so that no conflict happens. Is that correct?

Comment: @XiaotongSun: Java has no concept of "redeclaring".

Comment: I kind of understand it. So a local definition will never override the origin one, right?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you can create your own class or interface, which have an identical name to one that exists in the JRE already.

You can even create it in a package called `java.lang`.

But when Java wants to check type compatibility, it checks several things:

1. The name is the same
2. The package is the same
3. The class loader is the same

If you actually set `CharSequence`'s package to `java.lang`, then at runtime, when it checks the `StringBuilder` object, it looks for a `java.lang.CharSequence` from the class loader that loaded `java.lang.StringBuilder` itself. Your `java.lang.CharSequence` is not loaded by the same class loader, therefore it's not the same type.

However, if your error is at the compiler level, then it probably means that you have placed the `CharSequence` in a package with a different name (or in the default package). Otherwise, it would probably have been silent at compile time.

EDIT: In fact, it seems that at runtime the "local" `java.lang.CharSequence` is not even loaded, whereas the compiler can see it.